# Read binary file to write an image

Tags: binary

First of all, thanks a lot for helping me and being able to help.

I write in a .bin (binary file) a matrix which is a image. The code is:

```
QString outputFilename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "BIN", "/home", "files BIN (*.bin)");

std::string output_file_name = outputFilename.toStdString();
output_file_name += ".bin";

std::ofstream myFile (output_file_name.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    for(int i=0;i<img.width();++i){
        for(int j=0;j<img.height();++j){
            myFile.write (reinterpret_cast<const char *> (&matrix[i][j]), sizeof(int));
        }
    }

 myFile.close();
```

Now I want to read this .bin to write a matrix, so the invert process.
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For file operations exact data size is important, so consider defining `matrix` as fixed-width integer: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html. The exact type depends on image data (bits per pixel) format — http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/imageFormats/.

For reading, just use `read` function:

```
std::ifstream myFile (input_file_name.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

if(myFile)
{
    for(int i=0;i<img.width();++i){
        for(int j=0;j<img.height();++j){
            myFile.read ((char*) (&matrix[i][j]), sizeof(int));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!
The problem is that when I read the binary file I do not have myFile.
So the question is "How can i read a binary file to create a matrix 2D?"